# Javascript encoding after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I am using jQuery to change the `href` of an `<a>` tag in document.ready. The URL that I am replacing the tag with has encoded characters. The link works fine when I first load the page but not after a page refresh (F5).

My code (in document.ready)

```
var url = "/news#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D"
$("[href$=newsRD]").attr("href", url);
```

When I refresh the page the URL in the javascript stays the same, but it  replaces the `<a>` by changing all the `%` to `%25` The result is that the link no longer works. It gives this:

```
/news#Default%257B%2522k%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you encode the url twice.
You can notice that if you run in your console this :

```
encodeURI("/news#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D")
// will print your second result => "/news#Default=%257B%2522k%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D"
```

before encoding it, run a decode function to be sure that you don't encode an url that is already encoded.
Take a look at these ressources :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: You can `decodeURIComponent(url)` to get `"/news#Default={\"k\":\"\"}"`.

Comment: I understand that it is encoding the already encoded url, however, I am not encoding or decoding anything, I just do a page refresh and the url is changed, apparantely encoded again. I do not understand why!